# How to make VS Code Live Server's auto reload work in Firefox when using a proxied web server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, proxy-server, liveserver

In VS Code I have installed the [Live Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) and in Firefox I have installed [Live Server Web Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-server-web-extension/).

When I start the normal Live Server server auto-reload works (i.e. I change a page, save it in VS Code and it auto-updates in Firefox). However when I proxy to another server on `localhost:7700` (which serves the same files) via the settings

```
"liveServer.settings.useWebExt": true,
"liveServer.settings.proxy": {
    "enable": true,                            i. enabled
    "baseUri": "/",                           ii. workspace
    "proxyUri": "http://localhost:7700/" // iii. actual address
},
```

I've got a page served on localhost:5500 through Live Server, which is great. However, the auto-reload feature isn't functioning as expected.

How to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? (Please note, I have to use Firefox and cannot switch to Chrome.)

Comment: What does the Firefox extension do? I use the Live Server VSCode plugin all the time and it works fine without any Firefox extensions.

Comment: @ChrisBarr From My understanding the accompanying Browser extension makes it possible to use another, external web server to deliver the pages ( e.g. serving PHP or JSP content).